# Is it possible to verify, how does server performs while sending files/images to many devices using Apache Jmeter?

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, jmeter

I have to verify server performance by sending images from server to many iOS devices, but I have only three iOS devices.
So anyone please tell me, that how I can test this scenario using Jmeter.

Comment: You need to record or generate all web request from application to server and load with appropriate user scenario like Login > perform action > logout. Also you need to check Server performance by using any performance monitoring tool at server side which may differ with server platform. Please ask question specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to record your test case by one iOS device via JMeter [HTTP Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder). For this you need to configure your iOS device to use JMeter as a proxy. After capturing requests flow you can parametrize your test by amending values in [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to represent different iOS devices like iPod touch, iPhone, iPad, etc. and add necessary load scenario.

See [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide for how-to and more details.